# Values input as "0000000000" but when display its "0"

Tags: java, grails, input, controller

I've met with some troubles in inputting of values and displaying of the input value. What happened is I'm trying to input values in to the database with a string of "00000000000000" however when the results is being displayed out, it's displayed as "0". I'm using grails, MSSQL as database. Does anyone know why? Needing some kind of explanation and solution for this. Thank you guys so much :)

Comment: Are you sure your database column has `VARCHAR` type and not a numeric like `INTEGER` or `DECIMAL` ?

Comment: It's a integer data type. Is there any sort of explanation for this? Will get it change to varchar if needed.

Comment: Of course, `int` will **NEVER** save a `VARCHAR` data, it will save only, uhm, integer values (no floating points, no decimals, no BLOB data, just integer). If you need to save it as "0000000", then you need a `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure of following!

- You are inserting a String in to DB.
- And the column is of Varchar type.
- You are reading/displaying it as a String.

Comment: From now on, I will never post a comment that contains the hint for the answer =\. By the way, *I'm trying to input values in to the database with a string of "00000000000000"* will drop the first point of your answer.

Comment: lol! didnt expect this! i will delete my answer if this hurts you!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza When you are sure that something is solution, post it as answer, because most likely future readers will read answers first, rather then comments. ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Already seven up votes for your comments :P Not bad at all ;) You deserve!